# Timing Code segments execution time inside a large method

Tags: java, stopwatch

I would like to know how long it takes to run many code segments inside a large method.

I use `System.nanoTime()` to record the timestamp. Afterwards, I subtract two timestamps, such as `nano2-nano1`, to get the execution durations.

```
public static void largeMehod() {
    
    long nano1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
    
    long nano2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
    
    long nano3 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
    
    long nano4 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("put together, 1-2=%s 2-3=%s 3-4=%s%n", nano2 - nano1, nano3 - nano2, nano4 - nano3);
}
```

Problem here:

1. I have to manually write code to name those variables and format the strings, it is  inefficient and likely to introduce bugs
2. I have to remove such inefficient codes before I submit it to production, which can also introduce bugs

##### what I tried

With guava stopwatch:

```
public static void largeMehod() {

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");

    stopwatch.stop();
    Duration elapse12 = stopwatch.elapsed();
    
    stopwatch.reset();
    stopwatch.start();
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
    stopwatch.stop();
    Duration elapsed23 = stopwatch.elapsed();

    stopwatch.reset();
    stopwatch.start();
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
    stopwatch.stop();
    Duration elapsed34 = stopwatch.elapsed();

    System.out.printf("put together, 1-2=%s 2-3=%s 3-4=%s%n", elapse12, elapsed23, elapsed34);
}
```

It does help a little for naming variables, but it looks messier with `.reset()` and `.stop()` method calls.

Could you give me some advice? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can chain methods together: `stopwatch.reset().start()`. Also, you don't need to stop before calling `elapsed()`. So you can shorten your code like this:

```
stopwatch.reset().start();
System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
Duration elapsed23 = stopwatch.elapsed();
```

You can even create a method that runs some code and times it:

```
public static Duration measureTime(Callable<Void> code) {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    code.call();
    return stopwatch.elapsed();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Duration elapsed23 = measureTime(() -> {
    System.out.println("it takes a long time ~N sec");
});
```

However, if the `measureTime` method is the only place where you use `Stopwatch` then you don't need to load this class just for this usage. You can just use the standard `System` class:

```
public static Duration measureTime(Callable<Void> code) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    code.call();
    return Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - start);
}
```

If you are doing this all over in a large application, you should consider using [Open Telemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/traces/). This would be the "professional" way, but it is a very steep learning curve and it also requires a certain infrastructure to be in place at deployment, so it's something you should only do if you are already using software for viewing metrics.

Comment: It will create new Stopwatch instance each time call measureTime, right? I don`t think I would want that, but other than that, it is great. Thanks for quick reply